# variable as ID in R for clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a data set which contains 8 variables and 21.571 rows. It is a mixed data set with numerical and ordinal variables, of which one variable contains the ID. The ordinal variables are also in numbers.

I would like to cluster the data with three different algorithms. One of them is the k-means clustering. However, i don't know how to 'tell' R that the variable BELNR is the ID (the id nrs occur in multiple rows).

I can't use as.rowname because the identification numbers appear several times in the data. 
I would like to contain these id numbers so i can check later on which numbers are the outliers.

Part of my data:

This is a part of my data frame:

BELNR CPUTM    DMBTR HKONT HOLIDAY DAYWEEK AWTYP BSCHL

1 200012577    10    90.15 15400       0       3     3    25

2 190008604    15 13287.56 15400       0       5     3    31

3 520018342     8   423.50 15400       0       6     7    31

All the variables are ordinal except DMBTR and CPPUTM

Thanks in advance

Comment: side note: you'll need k-modes instead of k-means if you want to cluster categorical data. in general: the easiest approach would be to condense the data into one row per object.

Comment: Posting some code and data would be nice.

Comment: no one? I looked at k-modes but that uses only categorical data in R right?